# Two class properties that point to the same related object

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, model-view-controller, h2

In a request(request is for vacation days dates), that an employee can send, it needs to be clear who sent the request and who approved it(manager approves it), that's why I have requester and approver fields.
I have employee class in which(besides username, email etc.) I have a role filed(role is an enum - it has 'ADMIN', 'MANAGER' and 'STAFF_MEMBER') so I can distinguish who is who.
I have an bidirectional relationship between Request and Employee, my question is:
How to do the mappedBy part if the field('requests') is connected with two fields that use @JoinColumn on the same id(of table Employee).
In my example i put mappedBy = "requester" but does it also need to be connected with "approver" also?

Employee.Java

```
package com.incompatibleTypes.plancation.plancationapp.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String mail;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private Department department;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "requester")
    private Set<Request> requests = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vacation_day_id")
    private VacationDay minimalVacationDay;
    //private int total_vacation_days; // moze bit field, ali bolje kalk. vrijednost
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "minimalVacationDay_employee",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bonus_vacation_day_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    )
    private Set<BonusVacationDay> bonusVacationDays = new HashSet<>();
    private LocalDateTime dateEmployed;
}
```

Request.java

```
package com.incompatibleTypes.plancation.plancationapp.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Entity
public class Request {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_id")
    private Set<File> files = new HashSet<>();
    private LocalDateTime timeCreated;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee requester;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Employee approver;
}
```

I just put mappedBy = "requester" to see if the program will run, and it did, no errors.

Comment: What exactly is your question if your code works? Also, your `Request`entity does not match your description. You say you have two foreign keys, but in your code, you have only one, which is `request.employee_id`. You have no separate requester and approver columns.

Comment: You'are right I understand.
I meant to say is there are 2 fields that reference employee_id, but I want to distinguish them by the role field that employee class has(if that is possible).
And the initial question was how to do the mappedBy if it was mapped by the requester AND the approver, or is it just a wrong approach of doing it.

Comment: I'm going to use roles for different login interfaces and rights.
example when admin logs in he has a different interface with a right to remove an manager and appoint another one.
staff member can only sent requests for days of and see how many does he have left

Comment: You can't distinguish those two fields because you use the same column for them (`request.employee_id`). The way you currently wrote your code, `approver` is a readonly copy of whatever is in `requester`. Whatever you put in `approver` is just ignored. Your code makes no sense.